# Decreasing the number of negative examples with respect to the positive examples produces good prediction with SVM

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

### Inroduction

We have a binary classification problem and we want to learn a linear SVM (support vector machine). The dataset is composed of:

- **502** positive examples
- **5020** negative examples
- An example is a tfidf vector of real numbers of dimension **169647** computed on wikipedia texts.

The dataset can be downloaded from [E0518966_100](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nZFucr_RT9TjhOdThhcWU1T3M). In order to test our model we use the [Liblinear](https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear) library.

---

### Problem

For a given query represented by the following [vector](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6nZFucr_RT9RDlRRUdQaDRIeTg). If we train the classifier by using `502` positive examples and `5020` negative examples. The classification will produce the following probabilities:

```
labels 1 0
0 0.236806 0.763194
```

Meaning that we didn't classify the query correctly.

On the other hand when we use `502` positive examples and we randomly select `50` negative examples. The classification produces:

```
labels 1 0
1 0.758789 0.241211
```

Meaning that the classifier gave us the right prediction.

---

### Question

I can't explain why when we use **less negative examples** than **positive examples** we manage to get a **good** prediction.

---

### Implementation

**Step 1**: Split file into positive and negative datasets

```
cat E0518966_100.txt | awk 'NR >= 1  && NR <= 502 { print }' > positive_2.txt
cat E0518966_100.txt | awk 'NR >= 503  && NR <= 5522 { print }' > negative_2.txt
```

**Step2:** Randomly select **50** negative examples and combine files

```
sort -R negative_2.txt | head -n 50 > sub_negative_2.txt
cat positive_2.txt sub_negative_2.txt > train_2.t
```

**Step3:** Classification

```
 #Select random subset of negative examples
./train -s 0  train_2.t train_model_1
./predict -b 1 query_test2.txt train_model_1 prob_1.txt

 #NO random subset selection of negative examples
./train -s 0  E0518966_100.txt train_model_1
./predict -b 1 query_test2.txt train_model_1 prob_1.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an anomaly caused by your use of a discontinuous improper accuracy scoring rule.  Use an efficient non-arbitrary scoring rule that is designed for this case, related to log-likelihood or the Brier score.  No good measure of predictive discrimination would make things better by deleting data.

Your sample size of just over 5000 is likely too small for split sample validation to work, because splitting again would result in different predictions and accuracy.  You might consider the optimism bootstrap to bias (overfitting) correct the apparent accuracy such as Brier score.

In terms of the sample, get the largest sample you can and let the ratio of positives to negatives reflect the prevalence of the population to which you want to apply the predictions.

The logistic regression model and other probability estimators can ultimately be used to classify, if needed, once you specify the loss/cost/utility function.  Probability estimators also give you something quite magic: intermediate probabilities for which you might "punt" and not classify the observations.

Comment: Since the prediction is computed on one sample only here, I guess using the Brier score would not change anything at testing time. Thus, I assume you suggest to use it at learning time (loss). Would you have a reference to expalin how to do this ?

Comment: I'll add to my answer.

Comment: Maybe Hani Goc should precise more clearly that he uses a SVM (support vector machine)

Comment: Not certain that would change the issues.